# Magento 2 Cart Summary loading after code execution

Tags: magento2, javascript

When I visit the checkout page, the checkout summary loads after my `custom.js` file. This means when i'm trying to pull values from the summary to perform some logic on these values always return null.

Is there any way of me setting my `custom.js` file as the last file that gets loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/web/js/custom.js`

   your js functions goes here **exemple :**

   ```
   define(['jquery'], function($){
       "use strict";
       return function hello()
       {
           alert('Bonjour Amir');
       }
   });
   ```
2. `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/requirejs-config.js`

   ```
   var config = {
       map: {
           '*': {
               checkoutjs: 'Magento_Checkout/js/custom'
           }
       }

   };
   ```
3. `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml`

   Here we call our js function otherwise, the js will not be **loaded** !

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       require(['jquery', 'checkoutjs'], function($, hello) {
           hello();
       });
   </script>
   ```
4. - Clean all this folder contents `pub/static` except `.htaccess`
   - Clean all this folder contents `var/view_preprocessed`
   - Clean all this folder contents `var/cache`
   - Deploy the `static-content`: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Where about's do I put the code for onepage.phtml? Theres already quite a bit of stuff in that file. Also, where does requirejs-config.js go? Will this just sit as the top level outside of the Magento modules?

Comment: you can try below file 
`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml` or create custom js like above step

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was. Where abouts do I place the code-block within onepage.phtml? There are other scripts in there already. I presume by just placing it amongst the other script tags this will work. Also for the requirejs-config.js does this file already exist or is this an additional file I have to create myself? Thanks again

Comment: you can create new script in end of `onepage.phtml` file 
`<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'checkoutjs'], function($, hello) {
        hello();
    });
</script>`

Comment: `requirejs-config.js` not create additional file you can add in existing file

Comment: Please check and accept the answer if it's helpful.

Comment: Just making sure everything works. I will upvote and accept as soon as its sorted. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88338/discussion-between-a-fletcher-and-rakesh-donga).