# Add custom jQuery code after checkout page load

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I added some `jquery` code on checkout page but its not working as because the knockout component load after the page load and my `jquery` code not able to find that `element(class or id)` on which I have added the jquery code.

Comment: can you add your script here

Comment: @JimitBhavsar, I just added a custom.js file in head block and added click event on shipping method radio button, and its not working when I click on the radio button.

Comment: @AmitNaraniwal you can follow my answer this is useful 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/257973/68695

Comment: @RakeshDonga I've tried your answer like explained, but it loads before the checkout page is rendered.